# numpy ScalarType and type hints from mypy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, mypy

I have a container class for 2d arrays of a given shape, that internally uses a numpy array to store the data. If the user passes a scalar to the constructor I create an array filled with that value with np.full, while if the user passes an array or array-like I check that it is of the right shape and copy it in a new array.

To do the check I use:

```
if isinstance(data, np.ScalarType):
```

but mypy complains about np.ScalarType:

> Expression type contains "Any" (has type "Tuple[Type[int],
> Type[float], Type[complex], Type[int], Type[bool], Type[bytes],
> Type[str], Type[memoryview], Type[bool_], Type[complexfloating[Any,
> Any]], Type[complexfloating[Any, Any]], Type[complexfloating[Any,
> Any]], Type[floating[Any]], Type[floating[Any]], Type[floating[Any]],
> Type[floating[Any]], Type[signedinteger[Any]],
> Type[signedinteger[Any]], Type[signedinteger[Any]],
> Type[signedinteger[Any]], Type[signedinteger[Any]], Type[timedelta64],
> Type[datetime64], Type[object_], Type[bytes_], Type[str_],
> Type[unsignedinteger[Any]], Type[unsignedinteger[Any]],
> Type[unsignedinteger[Any]], Type[unsignedinteger[Any]],
> Type[unsignedinteger[Any]], Type[void]]") [misc]

Is there a way to avoid the warning and make mypy happy, or a better way to do the check in general? I am using numpy 1.22.3 on Python 3.8.10

Comment: Are you using any of the `numpy type` extensions?  Have you read those docs to see what is covered or not?

Comment: @hpaulj I think I actually solved by adding

[mypy]
plugins = numpy.typing.mypy_plugin

to the mypy configuration file.